# Problems of NaN positions when converting PointCloud2 to pcl::PointCloud PointXYZRGB

Tags: openni-kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have tried to convert PointCloud2 message from openni_kinect to pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB. And I have some critical problem when I check position information of PointXYZRGB. All position data is written as 'nan'.

OS: Ubuntu Linux 10.04
ROS version: Electric
Sensor: Primesensor

The procedure of my code is like bellow:

A. get sensor_msg(camera/depth_registered/points) from openni_launch

B. convert sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 data (=pc2) to pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB data (=pcl_pc) as

```
 pcl::fromROSMsg(pc2, pcl_pc);
```

at this time, I check the data of pcl_pc data  like bellow

```
cout << pcl_pc.points[0].x << endl;

the result is 'nan'
```

C.  I convert inversely from pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB data (=pcl_pc) to convert sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 data (=pc2) for publishing to rviz a

```
 pcl::toROSMsg(pcl_pc, pc2);
 pub_pc_rgb.publish(pc2);
```

and I can make certain that point clouds data displayed correctly on rviz.

D.  Moreover Moreover I saved pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB into pcd format. the values of position in this case also 'nan' like below:

`# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format   VERSION .7   FIELDS x y z rgb   SIZE 4 4 4 4   TYPE F F F F   COUNT 1 1 1 1   WIDTH 640   HEIGHT 480   VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0   POINTS 307200   DATA ascii   nan nan nan 7.1023033e-39   nan nan nan 7.1023033e-39   nan nan nan 6.8275213e-39   nan nan nan 6.9197169e-39   nan nan nan 6.8278744e-39   nan nan nan 6.7356788e-39   nan nan nan 6.367262e-39   ...   ...`

I guess this problem is associated with conversion of data format. Because the type of PointCloud2.data is unsigned char and the type of PointXYZRGB.points is float. Inside of function pcl::fromROSMsg, they copy data between these two data structure using memcpy.  That's the reason that it displays correctly on rviz when I convert inversely because the function toROSMsg also use memcpy between float data(pcl::PointCloud.points) and corresponding 4 unsigned char data (PointCloud2.data).

Is there any idea about this problem?? or this only happen to me ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11750/problems-of-nan-positions-when-converting-pointcloud2-to-pcl::pointcloud-pointxyzrgb/) by [showtime](https://answers.ros.org/users/1298/showtime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will always find NaNs where the sensor could not detect a depth value, such as on metal surfaces, dark spots or looking out of the window.
Are you sure this is not the case here? Are all position values NaNs?

---

Originally posted by [TomTUM](https://answers.ros.org/users/547/tomtum/) with karma: 481 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2